# Find duplicate records with different values

Tags: mysql, group-by

I know how to query to find records with duplicate records based on a field or fields e.g.

```
Select Customer,Count(*) from Table1 group by Customer,Month having count(*)>1
```

which would give me a list of all customers who ordered more than once in a given month.

However from that select I'd like to:

- Refine the group to show only dupes where the product is DIFFERENT. I know if I wanted to do the same I'd simple add to group by `',Product'` but in my case it is `Product != Product` and I'm not sure how to indicate that in the group
- Instead of getting a list of just which Customers ordered more than one product in a given month a list of all those orders. In other words instead of this type of list from the group:

  Bob,December
  Mary,June

I am trying to return:

```
Bob,Widget,December
Bob,Pipes,December
Mary,Books,June
Mary,Cars,June
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If product field is in the same table, then you can use count with distinct on the product field to get the number of distinct products:

```
Select Customer, Month, Count(distinct product)
from Table1
group by Customer, Month
having count(distinct product)>1
```

If you want to know what they ordered, then join it back as a subquery to your main table:

```
select distinct t1.customer, t1.month, t1.product from table1 t1
inner join
    (Select Customer, Month, Count(distinct product)
     from Table1
     group by Customer, Month
     having count(distinct product)>1
    ) t2 on t1.customer=t2.customer and t1.month=t2.month
```

The distinct in the outer select depends on your exact needs.